# Getting Data is Null error while trying to fetch record containing false value in SQL bit datatype using Linq query in C#

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I am working in ASP.Net Web API .net 6.
I have a column isAssigned having bit datatype in my SQL table.
I want the records having `false value` in `isAssigned column`.
When I try fetching it using my LINQ query I get the following error:

> System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlNullValueException: 'Data is Null. This method
> or property cannot be called on Null values.'

This error occurs only when I try to fetch rows with false value in `isAssigned` column.

```
var record = _todoContext.OneTimeCodes.Where(x => x.IsAssigned == false).ToList();
```

Comment: it looks like on the server side you have a nullable collumn, but on the c# code side you have a simple `bool` and not `bool?` as data type

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I found it. I had a date column with null value, hence got that error. Made the date column as not null and the problem is solved.
Thanks.